# Decreasing sequence is inceasing by induction?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have the recursive sequence $a_{n+1} = \frac{2}{3+a_n}$, which is an alternating sequence, and I want to show that it is contractive. I want to first show that the subsequence of odd $n$, i.e. $a_{2n+1}=\frac{2}{3+a_{2n-1}}$ is decreasing for $n>1$. I thus make the inductive hypothesis that $a_{2n+1}-a_{2n-1}<0$. But then $a_{2n+3}-a_{2n+1} = \frac{2(a_{2n-1}-a_{2n+1})}{(3+a_{2n+1})(3+a_{2n-1})} > 0$.

How is this at all possible?

Comment: Have you looked at the base case $n=3$ before ramming the inductive hypothesis?

Comment: OK, got it. The sequence should be $a_{n+1} = \frac{2}{3+\frac{2}{3+a_n}}$, starting with 1 for odd, and with 1/2 for even $n$.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was supposed to say "applying the inductive...." instead of "ramming the..."; I was typing on my phone when I wrote that (tiny keyboards)